# Excel VBA Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

i need help for problem below:-
when have an empty row, i want next data to fill in on those empty row
i want data row 16 move to empty row 13
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4beg.png)

```
For C1 = 1 To 273 Step 46

For B1 = C1 + 4 To C1 + 5
Cells(B1, 6) = ""
Next B1

Cells(C1 + 4, 2) = ""


For B3 = C1 + 11 To C1 + 35     'range Row for description
For B4 = 1 To 6                 'range Column for description
Cells(B3, B4) = ""
Next B4
Next B3

Next C1


X1 = 12: X2 = 1: Cells(4, 11) = 1
For N1 = 3 To 10000
If Cells(2, 10) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 1) Then


   If X2 = 1 Then
    For D1 = 1 To 273 Step 46
   
     Cells(D1 + 4, 6) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 2)  'Date
     Cells(D1 + 5, 6) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 1)  'PO Number
     Cells(D1 + 4, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 4)  'Attn To
     Cells(D1 + 5, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 3)  'Supplier Name
     
    Next D1
    
     
  End If
  

     If X1 = 36 Then
     X1 = 58: Cells(4, 11) = Cells(4, 11) + 1
     End If
     
     If X1 = 81 Then
     X1 = 104: Cells(4, 11) = Cells(4, 11) + 1
     End If
     
     If X1 = 127 Then
     X1 = 150: Cells(4, 11) = Cells(4, 11) + 1
     End If
     
     If X1 = 172 Then
     X1 = 196: Cells(4, 11) = Cells(4, 11) + 1
     End If
   
     Cells(X1, 1) = X2 & "."
     Cells(X1, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 5)              'Item Description 1
     Cells(X1 + 1, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 6)        'Item Description 2
     Cells(X1 + 2, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 7)          'Item Description 3
     Cells(X1 + 3, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 8)          'Item Description 4
     Cells(X1, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 15)              'Qty
     Cells(X1, 4) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 16)              'U/M
     Cells(X1, 5) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 17)              'U/Price
     Cells(X1, 6) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(N1, 18)              'Total Amount
     
    X1 = X1 + 4: X2 = X2 + 1
 
  
End If
    
Next N1
```

Comment: Welcome! Oh, don't make things more difficult for yourself or for Excel! Add an auxiliary column with row numbers next to the data table. Now sort the entire table by the column B - all the empty rows are gathered in one place, it’s so easy to delete them all. Now sort by the auxiliary column to restore the original row order. Remove the auxiliary column. If you really want a macro, then record this sequence of actions using a macro recorder.

Comment: As an alternative, use excel's filtering ability to find blank rows and delete them.